# What is the best way to return value from promise_type

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine

I'm a bit stuck with coroutines in C++20. My attempt to create an asynchronous task:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Task {
 public:
  struct promise_type {
    using Handle = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

    promise_type() = default;
    ~promise_type() = default;

    Task get_return_object() { return Task{Handle::from_promise(*this)}; }

    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }

    void return_value(T val) noexcept { value_ = val; }
    void unhandled_exception() { std::cout << "Unhandled exception in coroutine\n"; }
    
    T value_;
  };

  explicit Task(typename promise_type::Handle coro) : coro_(coro) {}

  std::optional<T> Get() { 
    return coro_.done() ? 
      std::make_optional(coro_.promise().value_) : std::nullopt; 
  }

 private:
  typename promise_type::Handle coro_;
};
```

Dummy usage example:

```cpp
Task<int> Coro() {
  co_await std::suspend_never();
  co_return 1;
}

int main() {
  auto task = Coro();
  std::cout << *task.Get();
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is in `Task::Get()` method. When I'm trying to get a value from `promise_type` it is already destroyed. I'm trying to connect Task and promise_type with a pointer, but it looks a bit ugly. I believe there is some standard and simple approach for this.

UPDATE:

This happens only if the coroutine is not suspended. In this case the promise_type is destroyed before Get() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just learning coroutines myself, but I believe that the way to fix this is to change how the `Task` is destroyed.

At the moment, you have `final_suspend` return `std::suspend_never`. So control returns immediately to the caller (`main`) and the `promise` is destroyed. In that case, you have to do something like this:

> I'm trying to connect Task and promise_type with a pointer, but it looks a bit ugly

Basically so that the `promise` can write its `return_value` into the `Task`.

---

But we could do it a little bit differently. You could *always* suspend:

```cpp
std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
```

And ensure that the `Task` itself destroys the coroutine:

```cpp
~Task() {
    if (coro_) coro_.destroy();
}
```

This way, the `promise` isn't destroyed until `task` is destroyed, which means that `task.Get()` isn't accessing a dangling... coroutine. You can see the difference [here](https://godbolt.org/z/es516hdrb).